# Django inheritance base class super

Tags: django, tastypie

I would like to use inheritance and have all my resources inheritance from a base resource class.

You will see what I have tried so far below. My issues is I now need to add in the meta class at it seems to overwrite at the moment. How can this be done?

```
class BasedModelResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
        authorization = UserObjectsOnlyAuthorization()



class AccountResource(BasedModelResource):
    """
    Account Object Resource
    """
    class Meta:
        queryset = Account.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'account'
```

Comment: Have you already checked https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#meta-inheritance ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a workaround:

[Resource Meta Inheritance](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/issues/98)

Also look at: [Tastypie Meta Inheritance](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/issues/16)

Answer (score 0):

Inherit Meta explicitly and separately from the Resource, as it's a separately-defined class:

```
class CommonMeta:
    abstract = True
    authentication = SessionAuthentication()
    authorization= Authorization()      
    allowed_methods = ('get', 'post', 'put', 'delete', 'patch')

class MyResource(ModelResource):
    ...

    class Meta(CommonMeta):
        # Inherits CommonMeta's properties. 
        # Note: abstract will become False automatically.

        queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'my_model'
```